# Uninstall Jupyter notebook completely using conda

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda

Lately I am having some problems with some extensions of jupyter and that are of extreme importance for my research. To solve these problems once and for all, I would like to know how I can completely uninstall, using conda, Jupyter and their extensions and then install correctly. Because .js extensions are not being recognized, as well as widgets.

Comment: Please add more details on what you already tried, and does the online solution work on the Conda site?